# WordPress Short-code inside a Post-meta text editor is not showing front end

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am using a simple `shortcode`  to add line space or separator. I added this `shortcode` in my post meta field where we can add custom description but this `shortcode` is not extract on `frontend`

**This is the text in my editor of that post meta**

```
Have you been looking for a better, easier way to enjoy your favorite [linespace gap="30"] Introducing the beautifully simple, versatile and discreet don’t let its size fool you.
```

where `[linespace gap="30"]` is that `shortcode`

**This is the output on frontend**

```
 Have you been looking for a better, easier way to enjoy your favorite [linespace gap="30"] Introducing the beautifully simple, versatile and discreet don’t let its size fool you.
```

this is my code for the shortcode function

```
function linespace_gap_shortcode($atts,$content = null){
        $arg_s = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'gap'=>'30',
            ), $atts, 'linespace' );
            
            //getting the values from shortcode
            $gap    =  $arg_s['gap'];
            ob_start();
    ?>
        <div class="clearfix separator-<?php echo $gap; ?>"></div>

    <?php 
    return ob_get_clean();

    }
    
  add_shortcode('linespace','linespace_gap_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my mind you need to add a `do_shortcode()` inside your template around your meta value.

Example :

```
$my_meta = do_shortcode(get_post_meta( 0, 'meta_key', true ));
```

**NB :** think about `esc_html()` inside your shortcode function or force `$gap` to be an integer for better security .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but still this is not working